# Scala: why does a `for` comprehension on a Map sometimes yield a List?

Tags: scala

Why, in the below code example, does `isAList`'s `for` comprehension yield a List, but the other two yield Maps? I can't think of any reason - the only difference seems to be that there is `isAList`'s comprehension declares two variables, and the others declare one or zero.

```scala
object Weird {
  def theMap: Map[Int, String] =
    Map(1 -> "uno", 2 -> "dos", 3 -> "tres")

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val isAMap = for {
      (key, value) <- theMap
    } yield (key*2 -> value*2)

    val isAlsoAMap = for {
      (key, value) <- theMap
      doubleKey = key*2
    } yield (doubleKey -> value*2)

    val isAList = for {
      (key, value) <- theMap    
      doubleKey = key*2
      doubleValue = value*2
    } yield (doubleKey -> doubleValue)

    println(isAMap)
    println(isAlsoAMap)
    println(isAList)
  }
}
```

outputs

```
Map(2 -> unouno, 4 -> dosdos, 6 -> trestres)
Map(2 -> unouno, 4 -> dosdos, 6 -> trestres)
List((2,unouno), (4,dosdos), (6,trestres))
```

I am comparatively new to Scala, so apologies if I'm being incredibly naive about something!

Comment: Look at the output of [`scalac -print`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scalac.html) to see the de-sugared program.

Comment: @Paul: I tried that just now, and although the output looks quite interesting, I'm not sure how to interpret it…

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Recently discussed on the ML:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/Cmh0Co9xcMs/D-jr9ULOUIsJ

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7515

Suggested workaround is to use a tuple to propagate the variables.

```
scala> for ((k,v) <- theMap; (dk,dv) = (k*2,v*2)) yield (dk,dv)
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> unouno, 4 -> dosdos, 6 -> trestres)
```

More on the tupling mechanism:

[What are the scoping rules for vals in Scala for-comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087014/what-are-the-scoping-rules-for-vals-in-scala-for-comprehensions)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! That mailing list answer makes a lot of sense.