# List Monad: Consequences of the signature of List.flatMap(f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, monads

Recently I stumbled upon some code that shouldn't have worked but did. This is a simplified illustration:

```
val l=List(1,2,3,4,5)
def isEven(i:Int):Option[Int] = if (i%2==0) Some(i) else None

for {elem <- l
     even <- isEven(elem)
    } yield even
```

That will produce `List(2,4)` and might be no surprise to Scala developers.

But it shouldn't work given that List is monadic and should be of this form:

```
class M[A] {
    def flatMap[B](f:A => M[B]):M[B]
    def map[B](f:A => B):M[B]
}
```

Following this definition, every element of a chain of monadic operations must belong to the same monad. Map transforms elements within the context of the monad and `flatMap` must 'trap' free elements into the monad. 
In the example above, we have this desugarized representation:

```
l.flatMap(elem => isEven(elem))
```

which is of type: `List[Int].flatMap[Int](f:Int => Option[Int])` and does not conform to the monadic definition.

The correct form of `isEven` should have been:

```
def isEven(i:Int):List[Int] = if (i%2==0) List(i) else Nil
```

Looking into the scala-docs, it turns out that the reason that `List` and `Option` can be combined in a for comprehension in Scala, is that the `flatMap` on `List` is defined as  `flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]`  and that allows for any traversable instance to be 'flatmapped' over. `Option` is traversable, `Set`, `Seq`, and many others are too.

I'm left wondering: What are the consequences of this broader definition of `flatMap`.

Are there cases that one should be aware/beware of?

Comment: A small point, but `Option` is not a `GenTraversableOnce`. There is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable` that allows the `flatMap` to work.

Comment: This flaw is part of motivation to create a more principled Maybe in Scalaz. See https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/728

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature you have listed is the notorious "use case", not the method signature, aka the "full signature".

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

You can build any target for which there is a `CanBuildFrom`.

The question is quite broad; I'm not sure the list of consequences has been catalogued.

[Is the Scala 2.8 collections library a case of "the longest suicide note in history"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-hist)

[The attempt to do so in the space of one talk.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jh94gowim0)

Or for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17377859/1296806

Comment: I had seen the two first links. I'm more interest by the last: Practical implications of this broader signatures have in day-to-day programming. One I figured out: E.g. for {e <- l; i <- s} yield e+i  could be affected given `l` is a list, `s` is a set and we flip their order in the for comprehension.